# store command output in variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am working on a script that executes ssh to few systems (listed in lab.txt), run two commands, store the output of commands in two different variables and print them.

Here is the script used :

```
#!/bin/bash

while read host; do

ssh -n root@$host "$(STATUS=$(awk 'NR==1{print $1}' /etc/*release)  \
OS=$(/opt/agent/bin/agent.sh status | awk 'NR==1{print $3 $4}'))"

echo $STATUS
echo $OS

done < lab.txt
```

The lab.txt file contains few Ips where I need to login, execute and print the command output.

```
~#] cat lab.txt
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
```

While executing the script, the ssh login prompt of 192.168.1.1 is shown and after entering the password, the output is shown blank. Same as for next ip 192.168.1.2

When I execute these command manually within 192.168.1.1, the following is returned.

```
~]# awk 'NR==1{print $1}' /etc/*release        
    CentOS

~]# /opt/agent/bin/agent.sh status | awk 'NR==1{print $3 $4}'
    isrunning
```

What could be wrong with the script? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You're setting the variables on the server, not the client.

Comment: You shouldn't wrap `$(...)` around the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, you are setting the variables inside the `bash` session on the server side and trying to read them from the client side.

If you want to assign the variables in the client script you need to put the assignment in front of the `ssh` command, and separate the two assignments. Something like the following.

```
STATUS=`ssh -n root@$host 'awk \'NR==1{print $1}\' /etc/*release)`
OS=`ssh -n root@$host '/opt/agent/bin/agent.sh status | awk \'NR==1{print $3 $4}\''`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two `ssh` commands. It also simplifies things if you run `awk` on the client rather than the server, because quoting in the `ssh` command gets complicated.

```
while read host; do
    STATUS=$(ssh -n root@$host 'cat /etc/*release' | awk 'NR==1{print $1}')
    OS=$(ssh -n root@$host /opt/agent/bin/agent.sh status | awk 'NR==1{print $3 $4}')
    echo $STATUS
    echo $OS
done < lab.txt
```

Comment: Tried running as mentioned, but getting these errors.                                      password:
awk: cmd. line:1: NR==1{print
awk: cmd. line:1:            ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: I've changed it to run `awk` on the client instead of the server.

Comment: Thanks Barmar. I worked, however I have to ssh login two times for same client system, the first time no output returned, second time it returns output of both commands. is that expected?

Comment: It's logging in once for each assignment, then printing each variable. Use public key authentication so you don't have to answer the password prompt each time.

Answer (score 0):

with one ssh statement:

```
read STATUS OS < <(ssh -n root@$host "echo \ 
                  \$(awk 'NR==1{print \$1}' /etc/*release) \
                  \$(/opt/agent/bin/agent.sh status | awk 'NR==1{print \$3 \$4}')")
echo $STATUS
echo $OS
```

Explanation:

The <(command) syntax is called [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution). You can use it anywhere where a file is expected.

Example:

```
sdiff <(echo -e "1\n2\n3") <(echo -e "1\n3")
```

The command sdiff expects two files as arguments. With the [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution) syntax you can use commands as arguments. ( e.g. fake files )

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: That worked fine as well with single login; thanks st0ne. I am working to get this included in the script.  I would prefer using multiple command lines and so can easily modify for any new commands to include; Is that possible? Would you mind explaining the different blocks used in the line? Thanks again!

Comment: @user3331975: explained the process substitution ... rest should be clear